# Update information on static HTML website from data.json file

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am trying to add a feature to my website to dynamically update information by pulling it from the `data.json` file. Currently, I am manually copying and pasting the information into the desired cards, and the process is very tedious, even though it's the same piece of code. It would be handy if I could just store the information in the `data.json` file, and the website automatically updates the main HTML code to match the updated information. I have some code written, but it doesn't work as expected.

Here is the function for updating the content on the website

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON('./data/data.json', function(data) {

        for (var i = 0; i < data.projects.length; i++) {
            
            $('#project').addClass(data.projects[i].section);
            $('#project-image').attr('src', data.projects[i].image);
            $('#project-title').html(data.projects[i].title);
            $('#project-blurb').html(data.projects[i].blurb);
            $('#project-link').prop('href', data.projects[i].link);
        }  
    });
});
```

this is the information from the `data.json` file

```
"projects": [
        {
            "title": "Stock Game",
            "section": "mobileapp",
            "image": "assets/images/project/StockGame.png",
            "link": "https://github.com/StockGame",
            "blurb": "Stock game is a python program"
        },
        {
            "title": "Real Time Translator",
            "section": "mobileapp",
            "image": "assets/images/project/RT-Translator.jpg",
            "link": "https://github.com/RT-Translator",
            "blurb": "Real Time Translator is a tool that can"
        },
```

This is the card that I want to dynamically update every time the website is opened, and the data is pulled from the `data.json` file.

```
<div class="isotope-item col-md-6 mb-5" id="project" >
                        <div class="card project-card">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-12 col-xl-5 card-img-holder">
                                    <img id="project-image" class="card-img" alt="image">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-12 col-xl-7">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h5 class="card-title" id="project-title"></h5>
                                        <p class="card-text" id="project-blurb"></p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="link-mask">
                                <a class="link-mask-link" id="project-link"></a>
                                <div class="link-mask-text">
                                    <a class="btn btn-secondary" id="project-link">
                                        <i class="fas fa-eye me-2"></i>View Project
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div><!--//link-mask-->
                        </div><!--//card-->
                    </div><!--//col-->
```

Currently, the code only shows one of the 7 projects, and the `project-link` id also doesn't work, meaning it doesn't redirect to my GitHub page. It would be wonderful if you guys could help me figure out how to integrate this with my website and make it not as tedious when I have to delete or add a new project.

Comment: You need to remember what executes where.  Your first block runs in the browser.  It doesn't have access to any of your server files.  And `$.getJSON()` expects to get a URL, not a file path.  Exactly where, on your server, is `data.json` located?  You need to have a URL that points to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In each iteration, you are targeting and updating the same set of HTML elements. For instance, using `$('#project')` to update the class and `$('#project-image')`, `$('#project-title')`, `$('#project-blurb')`, and `$('#project-link')` will result in modifying the same set of elements every time.

For multiple projects, you need to generate HTML dynamically for each project and append it to the DOM to display all the projects properly.

You can try the following way:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.getJSON('./data/data.json', function(data) {

    var projectContainer = $('#project');

    data.projects.forEach(function(project) {
        var projectCard = `
          <div class="isotope-item col-md-6 mb-5 ${project.section}">
            <div class="card project-card">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12 col-xl-5 card-img-holder">
                        <img class="card-img" src="${project.image}" alt="${project.title}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 col-xl-7">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">${project.title}</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">${project.blurb}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="link-mask">
                    <a href="${project.link}" class="link-mask-link" target="_blank"></a>
                    <div class="link-mask-text">
                        <a href="${project.link}" class="btn btn-secondary" target="_blank">
                            <i class="fas fa-eye me-2"></i>View Project
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>`;
        
        projectContainer.append(projectCard);
    });
  });
});
```